# Rollback all nested transactions when outer one is marked for rollback

Tags: java, spring, transactions, rollback, propagation

I've got two methods annotated with [`@Transactional`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html). The second method is called somewhere nested inside the first one.

Now I want the following behaviour to happen:

- Every time the second, nested method is entered, a new nested
  transaction should be created. When that transaction is marked for a
  rollback, only that transaction should be rolled back.
- But when the
  transaction of the outer method is marked for a rollback, every
  nested transaction inside — whether it's marked for a rollback or not —
  should be rolled back.

How do I have to set the [`Propagation`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html) values to achieve such functionality?

---

P. S.: I'm using a [HibernateTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [NESTED](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#NESTED). Note that this propagation mode uses JDBC SavePoints in order to achieve this behavior, and that the nested behavior thus only works if the transaction is just a wrapper around the JDBC connection. It won't work for JTA transactions. See the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#tx-propagation-nested) for more details.

Comment: It seems also that the `HibernateTransactionManager` doesn't fully support nested transactions.

Comment: JB Nizet, do you know any way to achieve that behaviour under JTA?. I am stuck in that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090428/spring-transactions-prevent-rollback-after-unchecked-exceptions-runtimeexcept

Answer (score 1):

One should clarify the default behaviour in Java Transactions. All nested transaction will not commit unless the parent commits. Read about it here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose to implement such functionality in separate threads, i.e. methods that you want to start in nested transactions - just start them in separate threads. It may look like following pseudo code:

```
//SomeService 
// Here we start an external transaction
@Transactional
    int processAllInTransaction() {
        List<Integer> jobIds = jobService.getJobs();
        if (!jobIds.isEmpty()) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    jobIds.forEach(jobId ->
                            //Execute eveything in external transaction   
                            threadPool.execute(jobId)
                    );
                }
            }).start();

        } 
        return jobIds.size();
    }

//Method of Executor Service
void execute(final int jobId) {
    tasks.add(taskExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
        void run() {
            someProcessor.processJob(jobId);
        }
    }));
}

//Method of another Service
@Transactional
public void processJob(int jobId) {
    //this will work in separate thransaction since was executed in another Theread
    someDao.doWorkInExternalTransaction(jobId);
}
```

If you really need to control external transaction - do nested transaction work in a single external transaction in new Theread and just wait for returned result from Thread and throw an Exception  if needed