# Spring Integration - JdbcPollingChannelAdapter commit instead of rollback on handled Exceptions

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-jdbc, spring-java-config

I am using `Spring 4.1.x APIs`, `Spring Integration 4.1.x APIs` and `Spring Integration Java DSL 1.0.x APIs` for an EIP flow where we consume messages from an Oracle database table using a `JdbcPollingChannelAdpater` as the entry point into the flow.

Even though we have an `ErrorHandler` configured on the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`'s `Poller`, we are seeing that a session's `Transaction` is still rolled back and not committed when a `RuntimeException` is thrown and correctly handled by the `ErrorHandler`.

After reading through this thread: [Spring Transactions - Prevent rollback after unchecked exceptions (RuntimeException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090428/spring-transactions-prevent-rollback-after-unchecked-exceptions-runtimeexcept), I get the feeling that it is not possible to prevent a rollback and instead force a commit. Is this correct? And, if there is a way, what is the cleanest way to force a commit instead of a rollback when an error is safely handled?

Current Configuration:

IntegrationConfig.java:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource<Object> jdbcMessageSource() {

    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(
            dataSource,
            "select * from SERVICE_TABLE where rownum <= 10 for update skip locked");
    adapter.setUpdateSql("delete from SERVICE_TABLE where SERVICE_MESSAGE_ID in (:id)");
    adapter.setRowMapper(serviceMessageRowMapper);
    adapter.setMaxRowsPerPoll(1);
    adapter.setUpdatePerRow(true);
    return adapter;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inFlow() {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(jdbcMessageSource(),
                    c -> {
                        c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(100)
                                .maxMessagesPerPoll(10)
                                .transactional(transactionManager)
                                .errorHandler(errorHandler));
                    })
                .channel(inProcessCh()).get();
}
```

ErrorHandler.java

```
@Component
public class ErrorHandler implements org.springframework.util.ErrorHandler {

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Override
    public void handleError(Throwable t) {

        logger.trace("handling error:{}", t.getMessage(), t);

        // handle error code here...

        // we want to force commit the transaction here?
        TransactionStatus txStatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(null);
        transactionManager.commit(txStatus);
    }
}
```

--- EDITED to include ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice Bean ---

```
@Bean
public Advice expressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice expressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    expressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.setTrapException(true);
    expressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.setOnSuccessExpression("payload");
    expressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice
            .setOnFailureExpression("payload");
    expressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.setFailureChannel(errorCh());
    return expressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice;
}
```

--- EDITED to show Dummy Test Message handler ---

```
    .handle(Message.class,
                    (m, h) -> {

                        boolean forceTestError = m.getHeaders().get("forceTestError");
                        if (forceTestError) {
                            logger.trace("simulated forced TestException");
                            TestException testException = new TestException(
                                    "forced test exception");
                            throw testException;
                        }

                        logger.trace("simulated successful process");

                        return m;
                    }, e-> e.advice(expressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice())
```

--- EDITED to show ExecutorChannelInterceptor method ---

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inFlow() {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(jdbcMessageSource(), c -> {
                c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(100).maxMessagesPerPoll(10)
                        .transactional(transactionManager));
            })
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("errorChannel", errorCh(), true))
            .channel(
                    MessageChannels.executor("testSyncTaskExecutor",
                            syncTaskExecutor()).interceptor(
                            testExecutorChannelInterceptor()))
            .handle(Message.class, (m, h) -> {
                    boolean forceTestError = m.getHeaders().get("forceTestError");
                    if (forceTestError) {
                        logger.trace("simulated forced TestException");
                        TestException testException = new TestException(
                                "forced test exception");
                        throw testException;
                    }

                    logger.trace("simulated successful process");
            }).channel("nullChannel").get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work just because your `ErrorHandler` works already after the finish of TX.

Here is a couple lines of source code (`AbstractPollingEndpoint.Poller`):

```
@Override
public void run() {
    taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

           .............
                try {
                        if (!pollingTask.call()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        count++;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
            ....
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Where:

1. The `ErrorHandler` is applied for the `taskExecutor` (`SyncTaskExecutor`) by default.
2. `TransactionInterceptor` being as `Aspect` is applied for the Proxy around that `pollingTask`.

Therefore TX is done around the `pollingTask.call()` and goes out. And only after that your `ErrorHandler` starts to work inside `taskExecutor.execute()`.

To fix your issue, you need to figure out which downstream flow part isn't so critical for TX rallback and make there some `try...catch` or use `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to "burke" that `RuntimeException`.

But as you have noticed by my reasoning that must be done **within** TX.

Comment: We do handle errors using `try...catch` but what we do then (for all our flows), is wrap the error into a business-specific `RuntimeException` which gets thrown back and routed to a business-specific `errorChannel`. I've created `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` (See bean in main question). To test, I've created a dummy flow with a simple service which has the said Advice wrapped around it but now, neither successful process or error process test shows the tx commit taking place. Is there a spring-integration-java-dsl example showing this Advice in use somewhere?

Comment: Actually, it looks like the Advice is configured properly and transactions are committing during success and error process tests. (Sorry, Eclipse IDE wasn't showing test had paused at a behind-the-scenes breakpoint therefore commit not completing)

Comment: One more question though, in my test, I wrapped a specific message handler (service) with the Advice. Is there a way to set this Advice globally so that it intercepts all Message handlers across the Spring Context's flows or at least across all Message handlers in a given synchronous transacted flow?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. By the standrad Spring AOP framework, bean names for `MessageHandler`s or just `MessageHandler.handleMessage()` point-cut pattern.

Comment: First time working with AOP... so to start with, I've created an `@Aspect` annotated class and I can make it intercept calls to a message handler handling a `@Service` component by annotating a method with something like: `@After("execution(* abc.example.service.TestService.consume(..))")` - this is intercepted ok but, I can't intercept the owning `MessageHandler`'s `.handleMessage()` call itself. I have tried: `@After("execution(* org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler.*(..))")` but no interception occurs in this case. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah... That's true. Because all Spring Integration components extends `AbstractMessageHandler` which has its `handleMessage()` as **final**. That prevents to proxy the method.  From other side, please, take a look to the `ExecutorChannelInterceptor` implementation option.

Comment: I've edited the flow to run with an `ExecutorChannelInterceptor` (See most recent EDIT). The Interceptor implementation doesn't do anything other than implement the interface methods at their simplest and I have set it on a `SyncTaskExecutor` over a message channel. Is this the correct way of using an interceptor in this case? Using the interceptor method, the rollbacks have been replaced by commits (which is great) but, I am now having problems making this method work over multiple concurrent threads. Is this not possible?

Comment: You should use there `org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel`. The `ExecutorChannelInterceptor` is supported by the Spring Integration since version `4.2`, which is in its `RC1` with `GA` just before SpringOne this September. From other side I can't say anything about your concurrency issue because I don't see the source code for your `testExecutorChannelInterceptor()`...

Comment: Ah, yes. Adding the `ExecutorChannelInterceptor` to an `ExecutorSubscribableChannel` instead has made a whole lot of difference. And the lack of full support until `4.2` probably explains why previously I was only seeing some of the interceptor's methods being called and not ones like `beforeHandle()` and `afterMessageHandled()` (which I can see now). Please ignore multi-threading issue question earlier (not an issue any more). I will run a full batch of functional tests on the full flows tomorrow just to confirm all is well and will accept and close thread then. Cheers!

Comment: After further tests and debugging, it has become clear that transactions are still not being committed (instead of rolled back) when the `ExecutorChannelInterceptor` is called. I can force-commit the transaction in the `afterMessageHandled()` method for example but, if I do that, the `TransactionInterceptor` still attempts to rollback the transaction and, at that point, a rollback exception occurs. Therefore, the commit occurs, but a rollback attempt also occurs. How can we suppress the rollback attempt?

Comment: OK. I see that I wasn't right. The `ExecutorSubscribableChannel` has a code to *re-throw* Exception after performing `triggerAfterMessageHandled`. So, any manipulation inside won't help. I see only the way to `try...catch` the target service to prevent rollback or anything else... Otherwise you should wait for the https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3770 or rely on the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` for each `<service-activator>`

Comment: In that case, we will go with your suggestion of the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` advice for each `@ServiceActivator` along the flow and we will keep an eye out for [INT-3770](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3770) to become available in `4.3` and see what the possibilities are then. Something like a `JMS DMLC`'s `setAcknowledgeMode()`/`setTransacted()` options would be ideal for us if anything like that would be at all possible with a `JDBC polling adapter` type flow scenario.